# mounted moodledata directory to s3 but when we purge cache it throws an error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, moodle, s3fs

I mounted my Moodle data directory to S3 bucket using fuse and S3fs on two EC2 instances. Now i am using both EC2 instances in a load balancer group, every thing is working fine till i am not purging cache. Once i purge cache of my application it throws me an error.

> Coding error detected, it must be fixed by a programmer: Failed to unserialise data from file. Either failed to read, or failed to write.

Please suggest how we can share Moodledata directory for two or more than two instance.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a permissions error.

Try this:

With crontab... Just after rsync or whichever method you use to ensure the data is sync'd and kept up to date, apply permissions to both Moodledata locations `/bin/chown -R www-data.www-data /var/moodledataex1`.